# Problem with the async mongoDB find() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to get some data from the mongoDB and store that in an array, then pass that array into the ejs file. The problem seems to be that while mongo is querying the results, the code after the db Code executes and an empty array is sent to ejs. Results come after execution of the render function and therefore no data is sent to ejs..

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    var batData = [];
    //console.log("get req");

    MongoClient.connect(url, (err,db)=>{
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log("Enter DB");

        var dbo = db.db("MatchDB");

        batData = dbo.collection("Batting").find().toArray((err,res)=>{
                console.log("Query Success");
        });

       console.log("Exit DB");


    db.close();
    })

    //  batData remains empty when these lines of code executes.
    res.render('index', {
        batting: batData
    });


 });
```

Output is in this order :
Enter DB
Exit DB
Query Success

Expected Order:
Enter DB
Query Success
Exit DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use promise here**

```
//change your query to function

functon query(){
 //now here return a promise
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   MongoClient.connect(url, (err,db)=>{
    if(err) reject(err) // reject the err

    var dbo = db.db("MatchDB");

    dbo.collection("Batting").find( (err, data) => {
            console.log("Query Success");
            batData = data//save your data here or do anything
            db.close(); //close the db
            resolve(batData) //this will get returned to the caller
    });//dbo find ends

  }) //mongo client ends
 })//promise end
}//function ends

//now in your app.get route

// see here i marked this async, for using await
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    let batData = await query() // this will wait until it gets resove or rejected

    res.render('index', {
        batting: batData // now you will have data here
    });


});
```

**Some points here for your help**

- A promise gets resolved or rejected
- the caller function for the promise will wait until it gets the result back from the promise function, again you can handle this if you don't want to wait for the promise to get finished
- async await are just way to handle promise in a more neat way removing callback hells from the code
- whenever you need to use await then you have to mark its function in which it lies async as you can see I did in the app.get callback function
- now await will block the code until it gets completed, rejected or resolved
- after then it will go to the res.render part of the code

Comment: Changed the find() to find().toArray((err,data)=>{...}) and it worked!  I knew that mongo functions can be executed with either callbacks or promises . I was waiting for a callback solution for this but this works too and looks cleaner. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

batData is declared as an Array but then later in your code you set it equal to the find query. You should .push() it instead or save it to a new variable and then .push() it afterwards.

Also, using const (instead of var) on batData would have thrown an error instead thereby showing this error. Unless you are using var for supporting older code, use const and let instead.

Comment: I used the .push() method earlier with the same results. Find() returns a cursor and toArray() converts it into an array. Right, i should be using let. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you are right on that one - I forgot it was converting it into an array. It looks like you followed Arpit's suggestion of converting it into a Promise, which of course was the correct answer. Glad you got it figured out. :)